# Сильное падение производительности на мобильном устройстве

Tags: android, c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, производительность

Возникла проблема с производительностью игры на мобильном устройстве/эмуляторе.

На сцене модель (+mesh collider) карты с текстурами  самого низкого качества(32bit), персонаж (+ collider, rigitbody). К персонажу подключен скрипт, в котором задается движение по оси Х и реализован взлет по средством AddRelativeForce к Rigitbody.

При запуске проекта на ноутбуке (i7, 8 RAM) в разрешении экрана 1920*1080 выдает 800-900 fps, потом падает к отметке ~250 fps и дальше стабильно. При запуске на эмуляторе значение fps ~15-30. Скриншоты экранов прикладываю.

[image]
[image]

на эмуляторе:

[image]:

Подчеркну, что на эмуляторе и на реальном андроид девайсе отличий по частоте кадров не ощущается.

Фиксирую в профайлере, что на устройстве большинство времени (ms) затрачивается на рендеринг, в отличии от компьютера. 
До этих проверок игрался с настройками Quality в настройках проекта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно, проблема в построении кода контроллера персонажа, а именно методы Update, FixedUpdate и LateUpdate. Пробовал разные вариации, на момент снятия показаний профайлера, код выглядит следующим образом:

```
   //движение по оси Х
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    //взлет
    void FixedUpdate()
        {
            if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) || isActivateJetpack) && isFuel)
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddRelativeForce(0, jetpackForce * 0.1f, 0);
            }
        }

    //двигаю камеру вслед за персонажем
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        cam.transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Lerp(cam.transform.position.x, transform.position.x + 24.4f, 5 * Time.deltaTime), cam.transform.position.y, cam.transform.position.z);
    }
```

Прошу оказать помощь.

Comment: Телефон гораздо медленней ноутбука, потому программа на телефоне работает медленней. Эмулятор эмулирует телефон, который медленней ноутбука. Вроде логично. что он тоже будет тупить.

Comment: tym32167,Но ведь мобильные устройства отлично справляются с играми на unity, а мой проект очень "легок" и прост.

Comment: Я про unity ничего не знаю, просто пытаюсь думать логически :) Просто вроде логично что телефон работает медленней. А как он должен работать в вашем случае я без понятия.

Comment: @tym32167, ну не знаю) у меня наоборот телефон быстрее компа

Comment: Ну начнем с того, что GetComponent и Update/LateUpdate/FixedUpdate(ваш случай) - вещи несовместимые, нужно кэшировать ссылку на компонент, а не каждый раз заново ее получать. Да и вы ничего не раскрыли в профайлере, для нас эти пики на  графике ничего не значат, нужно знать, на что конкретно профайлер указывает, рендеринг - дело комплексное :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, GetComponent убрал в Start. Вот развернул профайлер: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNlw8.png и https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4JRG.png

Comment: @ДмитрийСуворкин что-то с альфой. Тяжёлые шейдеры или ещё что-то. Проблема не в коде из вопроса.

Comment: @Suvitruf, с "альфой" как с прозрачностью? Если да, то такое возможно. Модель карты была создана в SketchUp. В готовой модели передняя часть видима, и сзади некоторые "стены" прозрачны

Comment: @ДмитрийСуворкин да. Просадка в этом методе явно говорит, что проблемы с альфой где-то. С прозрачностью нужно быть осторожным на мобилах.

Comment: @Suvitruf, действительно. дело было в прозрачности. Придется рисовать модели в другой среде. Заметил что, как на эмуляторе и на реальном андроид устройстве, фпс равен 30 и не на кадр меньше, но и не больше. С чем такое связано? Из-за чего ограничение в 30 кадров?

Comment: @ДмитрийСуворкин https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html